# Фильтр blur() в css ставит размытие и на вложенные картинки

Tags: css, html5, css3, blur, css-filters

Добрый день. Есть css код, в котором применяется фильтр blur(5px), но дело в том, что он также ставит размытие на вложенные img объекты, как это лечить и как с этим справиться?

```
.article_content_img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1120px;
    height: 360px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
     -moz-filter: blur(5px);
       -o-filter: blur(5px);
      -ms-filter: blur(5px);
          filter: blur(5px);
}
.article-img{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: auto;
    height: 360px;
    max-width: 1120px;
    max-height: 360px;
}
```

А вот, что в итоге получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура кода:

```
div.article_content_img > img.article-img
```

Как это можно лечить? спасибо.

Comment: Что значит `blur(-5px);`?

Comment: это случайно. Я думал, если на img поставить -5 то размытие уйдет =) сейчас правлю

Comment: Игнорировать фильтры в child компонентах нельзя. Вам нужно вынести выше (по DOM) вашу картинку и сделать его на одном уровне с блюренным блоком (как минимум).

Comment: Внутри дива находится только изображение, по тому коду, что вы показали blur будет применяться только к изображению. Может тогда просто из css убрать blur? иначе, поясните - для чего он нужен? и добавьте пожалуйста полный html куска кода что вас интересует(то что должно быть с blur-ом например)

Comment: "Вложенные img элементы" это что?

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
}

#foto {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  background-image: url(http://livefomdet.ru/uploads/images/f/o/t/foto_krasivih_jaguarov.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
}

#blur {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  background: #ffffff77;
  filter: blur(7px);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="foto"></div>
  <div id="blur"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: вопрос датирован апрелем)

Comment: И что, не надо или нельзя на него отвечать?

Comment: некроответ.....

Answer (score -1):

я вижу два пути решения:

1. Не использовать `blur`, а использовать png размытую (*что я настоятельно рекомендую сделать!! Ибо `blur` не слабо грузит страницу*). Если требуется плавная смена `blur`, то использую две картинки (с размытием и без). Добавляешь свойство `opacity: 0` и `transition`, на прозрачность  затем ставишь `:hover`. То есть при наведении `background` плавно меняется. Ну или не при наведении, добавьте то действие, которое требуется;
2. Вынести эти два элемента в отдельный `div`. Один из них можно спокойно растянуть и они будут друг на друге.

Comment: 1.Не использовать blur я не могу. Т.к. сайт расположен на modx. И фотография вгружается через tv.                                                                  2. Имеете ввиду, что img в отдельном диве и + div.article_content_img. И потом картинку с margin-top: -Npx перетащить наверх?

Comment: @KamilNHOT можно через `position: absolute`

Comment: Чё там эти 5 пикселей нагрузят то?

Comment: То что делают отдельные умельцы на реакте с бесконечными перерисовками в продакшен попадает